# Make HttpContext.Current.Cache refresh the cache every minute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, caching

I'm using HttpContext.Current.Cache. I want to store data in my cache for a minute and after that minute, delete the cache so I can put the data again whether it has changed or not. I want to do it every minute, no just in the next minute.
Don't know if I've been clear enough. If not, please tell me what is not clear and I'll try to explain it better.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. First, instead of using insert, we use add.
My Line should be this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("string", lstStr, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0,1,0), CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
```

I think this solves the problem. If I missed something, please tell me.